# Is it possible to create a complex filter with additional operands in Python FUEL SDK?

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, fuel-sdk, python

I am able to create a somewhat complex filter in Python using FuelSDK

```
from_filter = {'Property' : 'EventDate', 'SimpleOperator' : 'greaterThan', 'DateValue' : fromDate}

to_filter = {'Property' : 'EventDate', 'SimpleOperator' : 'lessThan', 'DateValue' : toDate}

 mc_object.search_filter = {'LeftOperand' : from_filter  , 'LogicalOperator': 'AND', 'RightOperand' : to_filter}
```

Would anyone know how to add in additional operands (like in the PHP FuelSDK) where I could include a Send_ID or Client_ID ?

Comment: This is such a terrible SDK I would advise you use the raw soap or learn another language that supports an SDK. the php and c# implementation seem ok

Answer (score 0):

Simply keep on cascading thru with ComplexFilter.

ie (in psuedocode)

```
Filter1 = {'Property', 'SimpleOperator', 'DateValue'}
Filter2 = {'Property', 'SimpleOperator', 'DateValue'}

ComplextFilter1 = {'LeftOperand': Filter1  , 'LogicalOperator': 'AND', 'RightOperand': Filter2 }

Filter3 = {'Property', 'SimpleOperator', 'DateValue'}
Filter4 = {'Property', 'SimpleOperator', 'DateValue'}

ComplextFilter2 = {'LeftOperand': Filter3  , 'LogicalOperator': 'AND', 'RightOperand': Filter4 }


ComplexFilter3 = {'LeftOperand': ComplextFilter1 , 'LogicalOperator': 'AND', 'RightOperand': ComplextFilter2 }
```

Now you have 4 filters.  You can continue nesting filters within filters to get what you need.